# Why can't I ssh or access web server on second vm running on vmware workstation 9?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 7 laptop with VMWare Workstation 9 installed.  I use Workstation to run two RHEL6 VMs.
I can ssh to my first VM from my laptop no problem, but the only way I can ssh to my second VM
is to first ssh to my first VM and then ssh to the second VM.  I cannot ssh directly from my
laptop to the second VM.  I do not understand why.  Any help is a appreciated.

The first VM has IP address 192.168.204.129 ...

```
[redcricket@first-vm ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig 
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:CD:AB:F5  
          inet addr:192.168.204.129  Bcast:192.168.204.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fecd:abf5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:623548 (608.9 KiB)  TX bytes:744029 (726.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12076 (11.7 KiB)  TX bytes:12076 (11.7 KiB)
```

... and I can ssh to from cygwin bash no problem.

The second VM has IP address 192.168.204.128 ...

```
[redcricket@second-vm ~]$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:34:DB:0E
          inet addr:192.168.204.128  Bcast:192.168.204.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe34:db0e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1738 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3837 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:180427 (176.1 KiB)  TX bytes:623977 (609.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:49032 (47.8 KiB)  TX bytes:49032 (47.8 KiB)
```

... but I can only access from my first VM.  I cannot ssh to the second VM from my Window 7 laptop.

I can ping the second VM from the first like so ...

```
[redcricket@first-vm ~]$ ping 192.168.204.128
PING 192.168.204.128 (192.168.204.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.204.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.716 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.204.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.480 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.204.128: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.476 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.204.128: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.468 ms
^C
--- 192.168.204.128 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3539ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.468/0.535/0.716/0.104 ms
```

... but I cannot ping the second VM from my laptop ...

```
redcricket@redcricket-WS ~
$ ping 192.168.204.128

Pinging 192.168.204.128 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.


redcricket@redcricket-WS ~
$ ping 192.168.204.129

Pinging 192.168.204.129 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.204.129: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.204.129: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Here's my Windows 7 laptop's ipconfig output ...

```
redcricket@redcricket-WS ~
$ ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::709e:73cb:3d7e:9992%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.21.77.85
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.21.77.86

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.ca.comcast.net
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:9:2700:203:1585:d702:3be9:dae0
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2601:9:2700:203:d4fe:865d:20af:3c0e
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1585:d702:3be9:dae0%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.108
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::22aa:4bff:fef7:cb59%11
                                       192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4dd:925b:7620:6276%22
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::843:8b09:a64b:7d09%23
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.204.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{31858BE6-6593-43AA-BB05-86411AA5F684}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{19E3EFC7-E040-4FE5-9241-B8DE273669B4}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.hsd1.ca.comcast.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.ca.comcast.net

Tunnel adapter isatap.example.com:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : example.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5efe:10.21.77.85%29
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Comment: Please post your /etc/ssh/sshd_confid and check if port 22 is open on the targethost. eg. netcat targetHost 22

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am 100% certain problem is not the `sshd_config` since I cannot even ping from my laptop to the second VM.

Comment: Can you access the internet from your second VM? Can you download updates and/or ping an outside address?
I have stopped using VMware a whle ago, so I am not familiar with the gui, some setting could be different there.

Comment: @Bruno9779 Thanks for your reply.  Yes I can access the internet from my second VM and the first VM too.  Maybe I should give up on VM Workstation and try Virtual Box (Oracle)? Any suggestion on what visualization product I should try?

Comment: What is the gateway of both VMs? it looks like a routing problem at this point.
If you want a gui virtual manager, virtualbox is nice and stable. There are many other command line virtualization apps available for linux, like kvm, but I don't know about windows